# I can't unplug PDB in oracle 19c

Tags: oracle19c, oraclelinux, pluggable-database

I am trying to unplug by PDB but it is showing the error that I have shown in the image. When I searched in google, this error occurs when we try to plug an unplugged PDB. But what I am trying to do here is unplug this testDB pdb.

**What Might Be it's solution?**

Error That I am Facing:

*SQL> alter pluggable database TESTDB unplug into '/u01/app/orabackup/test.xml';
alter pluggable database TESTDB unplug into '/u01/app/orabackup/test.xml'*

*ERROR at line 1:
ORA-65026: XML metadata file error : LPX-00202: could not open
"/u01/app/orabackup/test.xml" (error 0)*

Comment: Do not post images or screen shots. Please post the text of the error message in your question.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @pmdba. Now I have mention the error message  as text. Now Can you look upon it please and provide me it's solution in your knowledge?

Comment: Looks like the oracle process owner is unable to open or write to the xml file. The most likely explanation is that it doesn't have proper write permissions on the orabackup directory in the OS.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution @pmdba... I was able to unplug PDB successfully by your suggested solution. However I also found a solution for this problem but not recommended one. Instead of mentioning full path we can simply put xml file name, for e.g.: ALTER PLUGGABLLE DATABASE TESTDB UNPLUG INTO 'test.xml'; which works fine and was able to plug it to CDB by same way. But it's demerit is that we won't know the newly created xml file's location.

Comment: I would start by looking in $ORACLE_HOME/dbs or in your Fast Recovery Area.